# News extraction from Finnhub

Tags: python, web-scraping

Hi I am trying to scrape news from finnhub...below is my code...although the website says you can access 12 months' of historical news data...i am unable to get the data for more than a couple of days. Is there a limit to maximum number of news that can be scraped? Is there a problem with my code? Can someone pls guide?

```
    enter code here
import finnhub
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
finnhub_client = finnhub.Client(api_key="ca70hliad3i7itb1o5sg")

news = finnhub_client.company_news('AMZN', _from="2022-01-01", to="2022-05-31")
df = pd.DataFrame(news)
df['datetime'] = [datetime.fromtimestamp(x) for x in df['datetime']]

df.to_csv('/Users/rangapriyas/Desktop/News/AMZN.csv')
```

Comment: What you are doing is correct. Looks like there is some problem with the API itself. I tried the same and returning less results.

Comment: Thankyou! pls do let me know if there is any workaround...right now have resorted to manual scraping :(